# How can I get cropped Image to upload ? | React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cropperjs, cropper

I want user to upload and crop image for their profile image.
I user `react-cropper` [react-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cropper) and getting cropped Image URL. But I am not sure how to get cropped  image file so I can upload to server.

here is link

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wu-8z13i?file=/src/Demo.tsx:62-75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[React-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cropper) gives you a Base64 URL of the image.

We can convert this URL to a File object, as I have demonstrated in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-snow-fkw3l?file=/src/Demo.tsx).

As explained in the comments in that Codesandbox, once you have the File, we can upload the file to S3 or anywhere else you like.

> If you want to send this file to a Node.js server, you can use [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) with your Express server to create an `/upload` route. Here's a [guide](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/uploading-files-using-multer-nodejs/) on that.

Hope this helped. :)